# Where is correct information for 0x implementation on Polygon?

Tags: polygon, 0x

We are trying to use 0x protocol for trading ERC721 on Polygon. And I am kind of lost where is correct information. Could someone point to the right direction.

Contract addresses: where is correct version -  https://0x.org/docs/guides/0x-cheat-sheet or package 0x/contract-addresses?
Cheat Sheet doesn't have any for Polygon (neither production, nor mumbai),  0x/contract-addresses has very few (just proxies). Does it mean that 0x is not supported on Polygon?

For ganache-cli docker image  Cheat Sheet lists addresses, but 0x/contract-addresses does not.

Is 0x/contract-artifacts package is in sync with 0xorg/ganache-cli:latest docker image and Polygon mumbai/mainnet deployment?

Can I use contracts directly (with web3) or I have to go via contract-wrappers?

Is it possible to use fillOrder method of the exchange or I have to use orderbook with API https://0x.org/docs/api?

Answer (score 0):

For deployments not on Ethereum mainnet, you'll need to go through the link that says ["see other contract-address packages"](https://0x.org/docs/guides/0x-cheat-sheet#mainnet-1).

That will take you to the [contract-address package](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/packages/contract-addresses/addresses.json). The values in that addresses.json correspond to the different [chainIds](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/packages/contract-addresses/addresses.json#L254-L337). Check [lines 254 - 337](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/packages/contract-addresses/addresses.json#L254-L337) which correspond to chainIds for Polygon = 137 and PolygonMumbai = 80001.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to contract-addresses package, but it doens't have addresses for exchange, erc20proxy, etc721proxy and others contracts. Does it mean that I cannot use 0x v3 protocol on Polygon?

Comment: There aren't any officially supported deployments of 0x v3 on Polygon, but there are some that were built in collaboration w/ us you could use. Here are 2:
[Mumbai](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x9866c45224667061f8c9e66db38d9316a8d68951) Exchange Contract and [Polygon](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0C58C1170f1DEd633862A1166f52107490a9C594) Exchange Contract